# Is it possible to send GWT-RPC calls to another server?

Tags: ajax, gwt, service, gwt-rpc, cross-domain-policy

Assume that I've following GWT service:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
    String greetServer(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

I build & deploy client code on `myserver1.com`, but my servlets are located on `myserver2.com` (eg. `http://myserver2.com/gwt-module-base/greet`) & server1 allows cross domain resource sharing for server2.
Now, here is the question: How can I send gwt-rpc calls for greet service to `myserver2.com` instead of `myserver1.com` ?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need is to enable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in myserver2.com. I wrote a filter sometime ago for the gwtquery documentation. It works for RPC and RF as well.

[https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax#CORS_(Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing)](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax#CORS_%28Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing%29)

[EDITED]

You have to configure your service transport in this way:

```
GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
((ServiceDefTarget)greetingService).setServiceEntryPoint("myserver2.com/greet");
greetingService.greetServer(....)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I mean how can I tell GWT to send request to server2 instead of server1. Anyway, I found the solution! it can be done when creating proxy object: 
`GreetingServiceAsync proxy = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
((ServiceDefTarget)proxy).setServiceEntryPoint("http://myserver2.com/gwt-module-base/greet");`

Comment: In setServiceEntryPoint argument, use GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() as your server url prefix, e.g., GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "gwt-module-‌​base/greet".

Comment: Thank you for the CORSFilter implementation! Works great!